# equivalent of Console.ReadLine() in c++

Tags: c++, string, scanf, readline

[image: screenshot]
My teacher just gave me an assignment in c++ and I am trying to get a string with scanf but it only get the last characters typed. Can anyone help me please? I am looking for the equivalent of console.readline() in c++.

edit : I must also be able to store the value through a pointer.

so the picture show the code currently runnign in the background and it should have stoped at No assurance maladie : and waited for an input but it skipped it.

getline(cin, ptrav->nam); works but it skip a line for some reason...

Comment: in C/C++ => [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/), in C++ => [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/)

Comment: Don't use screenshots of code, make a sample that only includes **relevant** code and describe your input into it, and the desired and actual output. Basically, do some work on isolating / diagnosing your problem before posting a question beyond "I have this and it's broken".

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are looking for `std::getline()`. For example:

```
#include <string>
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
```

I've little idea what you mean when you say *I must also be able to store the value through a pointer*.

**Update:** Looking at your updated question, I can imagine what is happening. The code that reads the choice, i.e. the number 1, 2, etc. is not reading the newline. Then you call `getline` which consumes the newline. And then you call `getline` again which fetches the string.

Comment: Ya, scanf() reads words as strings I believe.  fgets(..., stdin) may also work.

Comment: Those are C functions. That deal with C strings. C++ strings are what we want here.

Comment: "string with scanf" I read as char *foo; not std::string foo;  I'm guessing "through a pointer" means null terminated C style string as well.

Comment: @user1732694 : What does that question _mean_?

Comment: You need to be precise. You said you wanted a C++ equivalent of `Console.ReadLine()`. The analogue of C# string is C++ `std::string` (subject to encoding). What data type do you want to use? If you want to use C strings (null-terminated strings) then you are most likely programming in C rather than C++.

Comment: what i want to do is to take a string typed by the user in a c++ console program and assing it in this variable : &ptrav->nam  ptrav being a pointer to a struct and nam being a string in the struct.

Comment: OK, you can do this: `getline(cin, ptrav->nam)`. That's because the string parameter is passed by reference to `getline`.

Comment: dosen't get any error but it seem to be passing over it and instantly skipping to the next line do i need to put a pause or something?

Comment: Screenshots don't allow us to run your code. Create the smallest possible program that illustrates your problem and post it. I think that would be a new question. I think the question you asked here has been answered.

Comment: Looks like `getline()` doesn't accept enter until a non-space character is entered. That is *hardly* the same as `Console.ReadLine()`.

Comment: `#include "string"` must be added or else you might get `identifier "getline" is undefined`

Answer (score 7):

According to [MSDN, Console::ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx):

```
Reads the next line of characters from the standard input stream.
```

The C++-Variant (no pointers involved):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

 int main()
{
 std::cout << "Enter string:" << flush;
 std::string s;
 std::getline(std::cin, s);
 std::cout << "the string was: " << s << std::endl;
}
```

---

The C-Variant (with buffers and pointers), also
works in with C++ compilers but should not be used:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define BUFLEN 256

 int main()
{
 char buffer[BUFLEN];   /* the string is stored through pointer to this buffer */
 printf("Enter string:");
 fflush(stdout);
 fgets(buffer, BUFLEN, stdin); /* buffer is sent as a pointer to fgets */
 printf( "the string was: %s", buffer);
}
```

---

According to your code example, if you have a struct `patient` (corrected after David hefferman's remark):

```
struct patient {
   std::string nam, nom, prenom, adresse;
};
```

Then, the following should work (added `ios::ignore` after additional problem has been [solved by DavidHeffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12806484/170194) by logical thinking). Please **DO NOT** use `scanf` in your code **AT ALL**.

```
...
std::cin.ignore(256); // clear the input buffer

patient *ptrav = new patient;

std::cout << "No assurance maladie : " << std::flush;
std::getline(std::cin, ptrav->nam);
std::cout << "Nom : " << std::flush;
std::getline(std::cin, ptrav->nom);
std::cout << "Prenom : " << std::flush;
std::getline(std::cin, ptrav->prenom);
std::cout << "Adresse : " << std::flush;
std::getline(std::cin, ptrav->adresse);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

new c++ supported cin and cout keywords. You can use those

[image: Ex]